# Streaming Dynamically Created .ts Files to RTMP Without Concatenation Corruption using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

I'm working on a project where .ts video files are generated in real-time, and I need to stream these to an RTMP server without pre-concatenating them. Initially, I attempted using a named pipe and FFmpeg to facilitate the streaming, as follows:

```
mkfifo video.pipe

ffmpeg -re -i video.pipe -c:v libx264 -b:v 6000K -maxrate 6000K
-bufsize 6000K -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -profile:v main -preset veryfast -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut" -acodec aac -ab 160k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmps://<rtmp_server>
```

To simulate real-time file creation, I streamed the files into the named pipe in separate terminal windows:

```
cat video1.ts > video.pipe & cat video2.ts > video.pipe &
```

However, this approach led to corruption in the stream.

```
frame= 1752 fps= 30 q=27.0 size=   24207kB time=00:00:32.32 bitrate=6144.8kbits/s speed=0.998x    
[aac @ 0x152687100] Queue input is backward in time
[flv @ 0x15262ed40] Non-monotonic DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 32368,
```

How can I achieve this task?
Any help is appreciated!